# Get Selected Item From Combobox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, combobox

I have a combobox with items from a DataTable, the ff executes when the form loads:

```
dbConnection = New SqlCeConnection("Data Source=Journal.sdf")
dbDataAdapter = New SqlCeDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM setting_unit", dbConnection)
dbDataAdapter.Fill(dbTable)
cbxSettingsUnit.DataSource = New BindingSource(dbTable, Nothing)
cbxSettingsUnit.DisplayMember = "name"
cbxSettingsUnit.ValueMember = "name"
```

The method when there is a changed in the combox box:

```
Private Sub cbxSettingsUnit_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbxSettingsUnit.SelectedIndexChanged
   tempString = cbxSettingsBusinessUnit.Items(cbxSettingsBusinessUnit.SelectedItem).ToString
   MessageBox.Show(tempString)
End Sub
```

there is an error at the line:

```
tempString = cbxSettingsBusinessUnit.Items(cbxSettingsBusinessUnit.SelectedItem).ToString
```

How do I get the selected item from the combox box?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this:

```
combo.datasource = datatable
combo.displaymember = "abbreviation"
combo.valuemember = "abbreviation"
```

then getting the selected item use this:

on **SelectionChangeCommitted** event of combo box put this:

```
    tmpString=combo.selectedvalue
    msgBox(tmpString)
```

Comment: Error: Conversion from type 'DataRowView' to type 'String' is not valid.

Comment: try : **tmpString=combo.selectevalue.toString**

Comment: nope, when I do that, it just returned, **System.Data.DataRowView**

Comment: what event are you using in combo box? use **selectionChangeCommitted EVENT in combo box** the put this **tmpString=combo.selectedvalue**

Comment: @PaulPolon: dont use **SelectionIndexChanged**, try **SelectionChangeCommitted** then put this code in that event **tmpString=combo.selectedvalue** then **msgbox(tmpString)**

Comment: May I know why using **SlectionChangeCommitted** work, and what is the difference?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43900/discussion-between-paulpolon-and-unknownymous)

Comment: please read this. : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/799d7d97-3a79-4453-9c0e-85996923c0fe/difference-between-selectionchanged-and-selectionchangecommitted

Answer (score 7):

Most of the .net *"listing-controls"* who have a `DataSource` property search for the implementation of the [IListSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ilistsource(v=vs.110).aspx). So if you set a `DataTable` as datasource, you're actually setting the `DataTable.DefaultView` as the datasource.

```
Me.ComboBox1.DataSource = myDataTabele
```

Equals

```
Me.ComboBox1.DataSource = myDataTabele.DefaultView
```

So now you have a ComboBox packed with items of type `DataRowView`.

```
Dim selectedRowView As DataRowView = DirectCast(Me.ComboBox1.SelectedItem, DataRowView)
Dim selectedDisplayMemberValue As String = Me.ComboBox1.SelectedText
Dim selectValueMemberValue As Object = Me.ComboBox1.SelectedValue
```

And this is how you should do it:

```
Private Sub cbxSettingsUnit_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbxSettingsUnit.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim item As DataRowView = TryCast(Me.cbxSettingsUnit.SelectedItem, DataRowView)
    If (Not item Is Nothing) Then
        With item.Row
            'You have now access to the row of your table.
            Dim columnValue1 As String = .Item("MyColumnName1").ToString()
            Dim columnValue2 As String = .Item("MyColumnName2").ToString()
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

So why did you get an error? Yes, you are trying to cast a DataRowView to an Integer.

```
'                                                                      |
tempString = cbxSettingsBusinessUnit.Items(cbxSettingsBusinessUnit.SelectedItem).ToString
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Dim row_v As DataRowView = comboBox1.SelectedItem
        Dim row As DataRow = row_v.Row
        Dim itemName As String = row(0).ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this

```
tempString = cbxSettingsUnit.Items(cbxSettingsUnit.SelectedIndex).ToString
```

Comment: Do you have web or windows application?

Comment: i'm still getting an error **Conversion from type 'DataRowView' to type 'Integer' is not valid.**

Answer (score 0):

try using below code

```
Try
        DS = New DataSet
        Tabel = "SELECT * FROM setting_unit"
        Dim CB As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(Tabel, dbConnection)
        CB.Fill(DS, "setting_unit")
    '
        Me.cbxSettingsUnit.DataSource = Prf.Tables(0)

        Me.cbxSettingsUnit.ValueMember = "name"
        Me.cbxSettingsUnit.DisplayMember = "name"
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
```